# Styling an Android edit text so as to look like a drop down / spinner picker

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-view

I have two EditText views on a layout containing a date and a time. On being clicked these open up my custom DatePickerFragment and a TimePickerFragments.  I would like to style the EditTexts with a picker drop corner as the following image shows.

[image: target view]

however I have not been able to do this, my text fields look like this:

[image: my current view]

The pickers all work and are hooked up and return values to the EditTexts, I just want to do the styling correctly.  I am happy to change the class of the containers from EditText if they should be something else to get the desired behaviour.  I think this should be possible as the first image comes from Google's own [design documentation](https://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html).  Looking through the EditText and TextView class documentation and xml attibute documentation.  Is there a way to do this?

I am using Xamarin to compile this down but that should make no difference to the answer.

Comment: make 9 patch image of bottom part spinner, set it as background of edittext

Answer (score 10, accepted):

set the Style attribute to the following:

```
 <EditText
        style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

use following image as background of your edittext

[image]

make it 9 patch with whatever colour you want.

Answer (score 1):

find an original image and Create a nine patch image like below..

[image]

**Note :** Black Lines are patches

And then add image to background of `EditText` like below..

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/box_edittext"
        android:padding="10dp" />
```

**OR**

You can use this simple way...

Define `style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"` to `EditText`..

```
<EditText
    style="?android:attr/spinnerStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```